# char pointer in C

Tags: c

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
  char* charPtr="see me";
  printf("%s\n", charPtr);
  printf("%d", charPtr);
  return 0;
}
```

I do not understand the line:
char* charPtr="see me";

how is the memory allocated?

Is 7 bytes of memory allocated and the pointer is allocated to the first byte? and

I know the sizeof(char*) is 4bytes and how does it matter here and what does it influence in allocation of memory?

Some one please help me.thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***`charPtr` is a pointer*** to an ***string literal "see me"*** which resides somewhere in implementation defined memory region. This string literal **should not** be modified and any attempt to do so leaves you with an **Undefined Behavior**.

> **I know the `sizeof(char*)` is `4` bytes and how does it matter here and what does it influence in allocation of memory?**

Since `charPtr` is a pointer you cannot use `sizeof()` to determine the length of the string literal. If you do so, What you get is the memory occupied by the pointer and not by the string. You will need to use `strlen()` if you need to get the length of the string.

```
         +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+----
charPtr: |  *======> | s | e | e |   | m | e |\0 |
         +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+----
```

Comment: "This string literal should be modified", did you mean _should not_?

Comment: I think you mean _should *not* be modified_

Comment: @Tudor: Indded. Corrected, Thanks!

Comment: "Indded" did you mean indeed? :D

Comment: @Tudor: Geez! I desperately need a spell check!

Comment: @user1632141: As I mentioned, `charPtr` is a pointer.All pointers on a environment will have the same size in C.The size of any pointer on your system is `4` and hence the output is `4`.

Comment: @Tudor, no. It may look that it works, but it depends on surrounding memory.

Comment: @Tudor: Calling `strlen` without a null terminating character gives you **Undefined Behavior**.So, it might just work or it may not.Simply, put it should not be done.On a more practical note, what happens is `strlen` tries to calculate the length till it encounters a null character and in the process it might read beyond the bounds of your allcoated memory, which may or may not cause a crash.

Answer (score 3):

The string literal is put "somewhere" in memory, such that it is available when the program starts.

The variable `charPtr` is allocated (typically on the stack), and typically using 32 bits on a 32-bit platform, or 64 bits on a 64-bit platform. In your case, since you state that `sizeof (char *)  is 4, the pointer will need`4 * CHAR_BIT` bits, which is 32 bits on almost all modern computers with byte-addressable memory.

The pointer is initialized to point at the first byte of the string.

Answer (score 2):

> Is 7 bytes of memory allocated and the pointer is allocated to the
>   first byte?

In fact, not really. Somewhere in *readonly* part of memory, there is allocated 7 chars, containing `"see me\0"`, and this variable points to it.

Difference would be, if you write

```
char charPtr[]="see me";
```

In this case, *on stack* will be allocated 7char (+ some padding) long array, where the text "see me" will be copied.

> how is the memory allocated?

It is allocated by OS when starting the application.

Answer (score 2):

The `"see me"` is a string literal and will exist for the lifetime of the program. Memory is not allocated on the stack and memory is not allocated on the heap for string literals. The string literal will be compiled into the binary, into a read-only region.

There is 8 characters in the string literal `"see me"`: the 7 characters that you see plus an implicit null terminator.

The initialisation:

```
char* charPtr="see me";
```

gives `charPtr` the address of the string literal. Modifying a string literal is undefined behaviour.

See section *6.4.5 String literals* of the C99 standard for more detailed information.

---

Note that:

```
printf("%d", charPtr);
```

is technically undefined behaviour as `%d` expects an `int` argument but `charPtr` is a `char*`: use `%p` instead.

Comment: *"A string literal is not modifiable"* without causing ***Undefined Behavior***, else it can be modified.

Comment: @Als, yes. Will qualify that.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the statement uses a const pointer.

```
const char* charPtr = "see me";
```

"see me" is allocated in read-only memory. `charPtr` contains the address of the 's'. The string is terminated by the null char.

Answer (score 0):

`char*` is just like normal pointer pointing first index of string .